# JS DOM issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null becomes Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is code that i've downloaded from a tutorial here: (https://codepen.io/Web_Cifar/pen/PoNNEYY) in hopes of adapting it to something that i am working on.  I've pieced it together and while it works in the demo (and there's a nice YT video where he goes thru it), it doesn't work for me in a live situation.  I am attempting to build a Gravity Forms-like multi-page data entry form (GF has some quirks that don't work for me).

The first Javascript error that i got was: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".  Researching that here on StackO, i got the idea that the general advice is that perhaps the DOM is not loaded for my document yet and we are calling JS before that has taken place, and two suggestions seem popular:
1). Move your JS file to the bottom of your HTML document, just before the close of your body tag (it WAS originally in my  tag... moving it changed nothing).
2.  Wrap your JS function in question in the following code: "window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {"
to force the DOM to load before calling the function.

Doing #2 changed the error to: ReferenceError: "changeStep" is not defined. There IS a function called 'changeStep' in the JS code.  If you reference the tutorial above, you'll see that it was originally the last function defined in the JS file, so i thought that moving it to the top would change it.  No dice.  I've done some checks to see if some simple JQuery tests work in my environment and they do.  I am relatively new to JS but i don't see why the DOM would not be loaded nor do i see why the function in question cannot be referenced.

Here is a skeleton of my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script> /* A recommended test to see if jQuery is working, and it is. */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert("jQuery is working perfectly.");
    });      
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/Me/Documents/multistep.css">
<body>
etc.....(moving to end of html file....)

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/Users/Me/Documents/multistep.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my entire JS script:

```
const steps = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form .step"));
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll("form .next-btn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll("form .previous-btn");
const form = document.querySelector("form");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    function changeStep(btn) {
      let index = 0;
      const active = document.querySelector(".active");
      index = steps.indexOf(active);
      steps[index].classList.remove("active");
      if (btn === "next") {
        index++;
      } else if (btn === "prev") {
        index--;
      }
      steps[index].classList.add("active");
    }
    });

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {    
nextBtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeStep("next");
  });
});
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {    
prevBtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeStep("prev");
  });
});
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const inputs = [];
        form.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((input) => {
          const { name, value } = input;
          inputs.push({ name, value });
        });
        console.log(inputs);
        form.reset();
      });
});
```

Please note that i wrapped basically everything in the "window.addEventListener..." tag (as per advice Googled above) and the only other change i made from the referenced demo (that works in codePen) was to move the changeStep function to the first function in the file.

I'm at a loss as to what is going on.  Can an experienced JS guy help me get un-stuck here?

Comment: I thought i'd add that the error happens here:  nextBtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeStep("next"); <-- (the first reference to changeStep after it's declaration just above.

Answer (score 0):

`changeStep` is defined inside the anonymous callback function of the first event listener, so it is only visible inside that function. If you want to access it outside that function's scope, you have to define it outside of the function, i.e. before calling `addEventListener`. But a better solution is to put everything in one event listener. I do not see a reason why there have to be three of them.

Besides, since you are still calling `querySelector` outside the event listener, it does not solve the original problem. That is exactly the thing you want to do after the DOM context has been loaded, so you have to put it inside the event listener, too.

So the solution is to put basically everything in one event listener:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const steps = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form .step"));
  const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll("form .next-btn");
  const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll("form .previous-btn");
  const form = document.querySelector("form");

  function changeStep(btn) {
    let index = 0;
    const active = document.querySelector(".active");
    index = steps.indexOf(active);
    steps[index].classList.remove("active");
    if (btn === "next") {
      index++;
    } else if (btn === "prev") {
      index--;
    }
    steps[index].classList.add("active");
  }

  nextBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      changeStep("next");
    });
  });

  prevBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      changeStep("prev");
    });
  });
});
```

This should answer your question about why you get the second error, but actually putting the script at the end of the body tag should have solved the problem in the first place, so the first error probably has a different reason. Are you sure that your script tag was at the very end of the body tag, and that you actually have all the elements you are querying in your DOM tree?

Comment: Thanks, I understand your suggestion but forgot to say that i had already wrapped the entire JS is an event listener and that just kicked the can down the road, with the new error being "Uncaught ReferenceError: nextBtn is not defined at multistep.js:24" (code for nextBtn.forEach((button),,,etc...).  That's why i wrapped each statement in its own event listener.  Doing as you suggested simply brought back that error.  Possibly the first error that i received was due to not having a body tag at all, since it was not in the original code that i started with.  Same error, different line of code.

Comment: I found the issue that i just posted about - bad syntax on my part (parentheses badly placed).  I am new to this, so i very much appreciate your help!  So, a <body> tag is 'required' in the html?  And finally, does the ORDER of how functions are defined in the JS matter?  For example,  "function a() { call function b; };  function b(){};  Thank you for your tips, much appreciated!

Comment: The `<body>` tag is probably required by the standard, but your page will still load if you do not include it. The browser will just add it automatically. The order of function definitions does not matter unless you do both of the following: 1) define functions by assigning them to variables like `let f = function() {}` _AND_ 2) call a function which calls another function which has not yet been assigned to the variable (whose name you use to call it) at the moment it is called. Just google Javascript Hoisting if you want to know more about it.

Comment: "Javascript Hoisting", will check that out, thanks for the suggestion.  Your tips helped me resolve this, thank you!